# Someone added a JavaScript alert() to my site

Tags: javascript

I went to my site to notice that as soon as I go to it, 2 seconds later an `alert(1);` pops up.

It only shows the 1.

After 1 -2 clicks of OK, it redirects to another site.

How could this have happened and how can I figure out how to deter it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security.  You might try asking at http://security.stackexchange.com/.